# In react-native-navigation, how do I update a selected tab bar icon without navigating?

Tags: react-native-navigation

Based on an action on a screen, I want to update the icon of the selected tab (specifically, a badge decorator on the icon representing an "unread count") without navigating to cause a re-render. What are some ways to do this?

Here's source code of a basic demo of the issue using the [tabs template](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/templates/expo-template-tabs) of `expo init` and then modifying to demonstrate: https://github.com/kevgrig/rn_navigation_badge_updates

Here's a snack of that repo: https://snack.expo.io/@git/github.com/kevgrig/rn_navigation_badge_updates

The key bits are:

- The `createBottomTabNavigator` in [navigation/MainTabNavigator.js](https://github.com/kevgrig/rn_navigation_badge_updates/blob/master/navigation/MainTabNavigator.js) with `tabBarIcon`s that return a `<TabBarIcon />` component and pass a `badgeCount` param.

  ```
  let homeTabCount = 1;
  HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
      return (
        <TabBarIcon
          focused={focused}
          name={
            Platform.OS === 'ios'
              ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
              : 'md-information-circle'
          }
          badgeCount={homeTabCount}
        />
      );
    },
  };
  ```
- The `TabBarIcon` component in [components/TabBarIcon.js](https://github.com/kevgrig/rn_navigation_badge_updates/blob/master/components/TabBarIcon.js) with an optional `badgeCount` param.

  ```
  export default class TabBarIcon extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const { name, focused, badgeCount } = this.props;

      return (
        <View style={badgeStyles.badgeView}>
          <Ionicons
            name={name}
            size={26}
            style={{ marginBottom: -3 }}
            color={focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault}
          />
          { badgeCount > 0 && (
            <View style={badgeStyles.badgeContainer}>
              <Text style={badgeStyles.badgeText}>{badgeCount}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
  ```
- A `Button` on the HomeScreen in [screens/HomeScreen.js](https://github.com/kevgrig/rn_navigation_badge_updates/blob/master/screens/HomeScreen.js#L33) with an `onPress` handler which I'd like to use to update the `badgeCount` of the HomeScreen tab.

  ```
  export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    onPress = () => {
      // TODO - how to update the badgeCount?
    }
  ```

I debugged the available methods of `props.navigation` and saw `emit('refocus')` but that didn't work.

Comment: This is pretty wierd request to get done. But if you wish to make it happen I really recommend for you to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view
It's better and easier to costumize. good luck

Comment: The use case is basically that the tab has a badge showing the total unread chat message count, so when a user selects a particular conversation in a sub-screen of that tab, I'd like to update the total unread count (since that conversation is now read). I'll check out that link although I'd prefer to use vanilla RN navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accomplished this with `react-redux`. Roughly something like this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';

const defaultState = {
  badgeCount: 0,
};

const ACTION_REFRESH_STATE = "ACTION_REFRESH_STATE";

function rootReducer(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_REFRESH_STATE:
      const result = Object.assign({}, state);
      if (action.new_state.badgeCount) {
        result.badgeCount = action.new_state.badgeCount;
      }
      return result;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function refreshState(new_state) {
  return {
    type: ACTION_REFRESH_STATE,
    new_state: new_state,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    refreshState: (new_state) => {
      dispatch(refreshState(new_state));
    }
  }
};

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

function routeToIcon(routeName) {
  if (routeName.startsWith("Home")) {
    return { iconName: "md-home", mapStateToProps: state => ({ badgeCount: state.badgeCount }) };
  } [...]
}

[...]
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
      const { iconName, mapStateToProps } = routeToIcon(navigation.state.routeName);
      let IconWithBadgeContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(IconWithBadge);
      return <IconWithBadgeContainer name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
    },
[...]

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer
          ref={navigatorRef => {
            globalNavigatorRef = navigatorRef;
          }}
        />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```